# Defining custom attributes in and loading other modules from AMD/Require.js module when necessary?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I am trying to define new attributes for a central controller (a backbone view actually) to make it more compartmentalised and structured. I try to separate the rendering I want to achieve in different cases by if statements, and implementing each case's rendering in those new attributes. But after insertion of the replacement code to achieve that and commenting of the code before it make my app not work.

What is the wrong thing I do.

Another way I can imagine to modularise it is to conditionally, again, to load different AMD/Require.js modeules I write, in a separate file/s, and load them. But How? Via require() inside the render:, or by new moduleName passed to the second argument to the define() below.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'ratchet',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/login',
  'text!templates/login.html',
  'text!templates/app.html'

  ], function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginTmpl, AppTmpl){
      var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

          el: $("body"),

          template_login: _.template(LoginTmpl),
          template_app: _.template(AppTmpl),

          initialize: function(){
              this.model = new LoginModel;
              this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
              this.render();
          },
        //Replacement code: two attributes:
          render_login: function(){
              this.$el.html(this.template_app( this.model.toJSON() ));
              console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model) );
              return this;
            }
          },
          render_app: function(){
              this.$("#content").html(this.template_login( this.model.toJSON() ));
              console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model) );
              return this;
          },
          render: function() {
            /*
            if (this.model.get('loginp') == true) { 
            this.$el.html(this.template_app( this.model.toJSON() ));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model) );
            return this;                
            }
            */

            /*
            else {
            this.$("#content").html(this.template_login( this.model.toJSON() ));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model) );
            return this;
            }
            */
            //Replacement code: 
            if (this.model.get('loginp') == true) {
                this.render_app;
            } else {
                this.render_login;
            }
          },

          events: {
              'click #loginbtn' : 'login',
              'click #registerbtn' : 'register'
          },

          login: function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var formData = {};

              $( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
                    if( $(el).val() != '' ) {
                        if( el.id === 'username' ) {
                            formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
                        } else if( el.id === 'password' ) {
                            formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
                        }
                    }
                    console.log( i + ": " + $(el).val() );
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData) );

                    // Clear input field values
                    $( el ).val('');
                });
                this.model.save( formData );
            }
        });
        return LoginView;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up with the above answer, the forgotten brackets,

1-render_app and render_login to render_app() and render_login()

2-correcting the syntax error: the second bracket in render_login's function definition.

3-either interchanging render_app and render_login attribute names or the templates used in their anonym functions. they se each others'.

Answer (score 1):

In `render` method your replacement code that call `render_app` and `render_login`, actualy did't execute them. Your forgot `()`

```
if (this.model.get('loginp') == true) {
            this.render_app();
        } else {
            this.render_login();
        }
```

Comment: But the code I have sent has a syntax error. Closing the render login attributes anonym function should be only one `}` there are two there.
Together with your answer and yet another thing the names of the render_app and render_login should be interchanged. their implementation has each other's template loaded.

Comment: At the beginnig of your question you have mentioned that this script works before change. So  I havent looked for syntax error like `}` .  The implementation of your if statement and method is your particular problem, you should decide which one to choose, not the answer writter. So having this things in mind please correct your syntax end logical issues in question and remove your added answer, cause in fact it's repeating mine.

Comment: My answer is the thing that solves the situation. thanks for your answer, but it was not sufficient to make it work. Definitely while replacing the code I mentioned I have accidentally added an extra bracket to the place, and this is not a different kind of problem in the code than you have suggested solution. Both are syntactic problems and the solutions. And the logical problem is another issue that can be another answer, but again not as complete as your answer and two of mine alone itself. And even more,your answer is mentioned in my answer to be belong not to me.

Comment: And if I delete my answer your answer does not solve the problem, and the question is intentionally left unanswered. And if I correct the error in the question text I destroy the problem then question is no more a question. I can correct the parts you pointed missing parenthesis, but that would be unyielding here. Here problems to be saved and solved and solutions to be saved, not to be saved and solved and deleted. Your answer again is very welcome and was helpful.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd case just syntax errors that occurs when you copy-pastes your code, cause before it works. 1st one is main issue. Thanks for referencing to my answer.

Comment: I have tried to explain you the issue you have referenced is no different than those I have done, especially the second one, both are syntactic issues. those kind of issues are also problems asked and discussed on this sites. If they were not in the code I would not answer my own question. Together they constitute 2/3 of the solution make code work. This is clear and not an issue.